# vectorization in functions with some tables as parameters

Tags: r, function, tidyverse

I need some help abot best practices

I have a function **fc_mean_wages()** that calculates a value (a mean wages) and do these tasks (rougly):

1. get as parameters the monthly wages of the worker (lenght **m** or less)
2. If I havent **m** wages, I look for the way to get similar replacement: 
   2a. get the median of the others workers from the same employer,
   2b. otherwise, I get the national mean for the activity
3. get a table of **m** indexes to adjust wages to inflation.
4. I compute the weighted average of the **m** selected values

I have to do this task with thousands of workers. So I can do two things

1. A. put as parameters the complete wage databases, compute all them with ONE function call.
2. B. put as parameters the wages of only one worker, compute all them in a vectorized way (eg: `wages %>% group_by (worker) %>% mutate(., index_tables, wages, activity_means_table)`)

I choose A because the function need calc the median of the same wage database and do not know if the vectorization works well when you have to put as input large tables.
My A solution is not a great function, it is likeness more a one shot process than a functional form.

¿Is it OK try to vectorize this task? ¿Have better performance call many times the wage table and filter it worker by worker?

Comment: State what packages you're using, it appears `tidyverse`, are there others?

Comment: I am using the `tidyverse` family and `lubridate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is a very complex task for a function.

I recommend you to divide it into simpler parts.

Even so, you would not be able to avoid reading entire tables to perform the lookups that you mention (look up for the media in employer's payroll). The solution is to analyze which of these tasks are volatile and which are not.

For example, the employer's payroll may change once a month. Then run the lookup process only once; it is not necessary to be a function.
Others like filtering the salaries of the selected worker may be needed on demand, so functionalize them.

Finally, use the `profvis` and `microbenchmark` packages to record improvements and document complex processes. Separate the *one shot running processes* from the core; later can be replaced by another language, can be delegated to the IT team, or become obsolete by improvements database design or because a better quality on data.